# create anchor id for each row id in table Python Flask

Tags: python, html, flask

**strong text**from flask import *
import pandas as pd
app = Flask(**name**)

```
@app.route("/")
def show_home():
    return render_template('base.html',)

@app.route("/mytable")
def show_table():
    data = pd.read_csv("Book1.csv", header = 0)
    myData = data.values 
    return render_template('view.html', myData=myData)
    
@app.route("/myredirect")
def my_redirect():
    return redirect(url_for('show_table') + '#42')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

### Base.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<p>
      <a href="{{url_for('my_redirect',_anchor='5') }}">5</a>
   </p>
   <p>
      <a href="{{url_for('my_redirect',_anchor='4') }}">4</a>
   </p>
</html>
```

###### I am using Python Flask and I am new to HTML. I have two tables. One is chip table and one is chip report table. I wish to click on the id on chip table and it will bring me to the chip report table in another html page and anchor to the row with the same chip id. For example: I click on ID = 5 on chip table, the html page will redirecte to chip report table html page and go to the row with chip id = 5.

When I click on 5, it should load the chip report table in (view.html) and jump to the row with id = 5

Book1.csv
1,24,34,25
2,10,22,24
3,12,13,15

```
enter code here
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the first few lines of `Book1.csv`

Comment: I have edited the csv file